# SAP Analytics Cloud - Measures option not visible in the Builder panel

Tags: sap, sap-analytics-cloud, sac

I am currently learning "Designing Stories in SAP Analytics Cloud" under which there's a sub topic "Table configuration". In their image illustration, I can see the option "Add Measures/Dimensions" [image: Course Image Illustration]. However, while on creating a table in a story I only get the option - "Add Dimension"[image: screenshot of builder panel in my story creation]

Why am I not able to see the "Add measures" option? I am not sure if I am skipping any steps here? what could be the reason, please enlighten me if anyone has faced something similar or has any idea about the same.

Comment: SO is for programming questions

Answer (score 0):

Is "G/L Account" a dimension or the model account? If it's the latter you'll want to click the Manage Filters button (shaped like a funnel, next to the X in in the G/L Account box). This should open a window to select the measures in your model.

For calculated measures click the 3 dots and select Add Calculation.